# Clean improperly positioned CR+LF in texts

Tags: text, replace, notepad++, data-cleaning, code-cleanup

I have a TXT file that I want to import to Excel to study. But, before the import, I'm struggling with the format of the text. It is  a completely mess, ass you can see:

```
| 1020941333    |     569|SP    |500000343 | 9|18.05.2011|15:27:00|18.05.2011|
18.05.2011|Y-0444871-ENCR    |           1,93 |BRL  |8000800000  |
Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |
                                        |    |          |     |
                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |
Y-0444871               |
| 1020941586    |      43|SP    |500000344 |43|18.05.2011|15:41:43|18.05.2011|
18.05.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           9,02 |BRL  |8000800000  |
Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |
                                        |    |          |     |
                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |
B-0447039               |
| 1021245920    |     956|SP    |500000489 | 6|14.06.2011|15:24:02|14.06.2011|
14.06.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           8,95 |BRL  |8000800000  |
Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |
                                        |    |          |     |
                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |
B-0447039    

       |
```

So I was looking for the answer of why the text is so weird. I found that it is like that because of some CR+LF (Carriage Return + Line Feed) improperly positioned. I did manually some corrections and through that I could see that it's possible to organize better the text, as it can be seen bellow:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Nº documento  |     LL.|TpDoc.|Nº doc.ref|LL|Entrado em|Hora    |Data doc. |Dt.lçto.  |Elemento PEP      | Valor/moeda ACC|MdACC|Cl.custo    |Denom.classe custo         |Material          |  Qtd.entr.|Texto breve material                    |UML |Doc.compra| Item|Texto do pedido      |Usuário    |DEs  |Est  |Nº ref.estorno   |Empr. |EmFI  |Definição do projeto
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1016939462    |       1|WE    |5000058364| 1|22.02.2010|10:52:43|22.02.2010|22.02.2010|Y0444871PROJELMC  |         540,93 |BRL  |8000124000  |Serviço de Terceiro        |                  |     1,000 |                                        |UR  |4501328844|    1|ESTUDOS E PROJ. REDE |CLB055760  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |Y-0444871               |
| 1020016002    |       1|WE    |5000053667| 1|15.02.2011|11:56:05|15.02.2011|15.02.2011|B0447039PROJELMC  |       2.011,84 |BRL  |8000124000  |Serviço de Terceiro        |                  |     1,000 |                                        |UR  |4501633481|    1|ESTUDOS E PROJ. REDE |CLB093440  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |B-0447039               |
| 1020258918    |     798|SP    |500000121 | 8|15.03.2011|18:06:18|15.03.2011|15.03.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           6,92 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB107395  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |B-0447039               |
| 1020585116    |     761|SP    |500000225 | 1|15.04.2011|14:13:44|15.04.2011|15.04.2011|Y-0444871-ENCR    |           1,88 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB145327  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |Y-0444871               |
| 1020586939    |     184|SP    |500000230 | 4|15.04.2011|16:22:41|15.04.2011|15.04.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           7,03 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB145327  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |B-0447039               |
```

I could see also a pattern in the text. Every line begins with this character `|`. So for each line that does not starts with ´|´ should be joined with the previous line.

The problem AS IS:

```
| 1020941333    |     569|SP    |500000343 | 9|18.05.2011|15:27:00|18.05.2011|
18.05.2011|Y-0444871-ENCR    |           1,93 |BRL  |8000800000  |
Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |
                                        |    |          |     |
                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |
Y-0444871               |
| 1020941586    |      43|SP    |500000344 |43|18.05.2011|15:41:43|18.05.2011|
18.05.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           9,02 |BRL  |8000800000  |
Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |
                                        |    |          |     |
                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |
B-0447039               |
```

The Desired Output

```
| 1020941333    |     569|SP    |500000343 | 9|18.05.2011|15:27:00|18.05.2011|18.05.2011|Y-0444871-ENCR    |           1,93 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |Y-0444871               |
| 1020941586    |      43|SP    |500000344 |43|18.05.2011|15:41:43|18.05.2011|18.05.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           9,02 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |B-0447039               |
```

I'm having a lot of difficult to implement it in Notepad++. I can't do it manually because the file has more than 4.9 million lines. I really appreciate if someone could show me some light about this problem, using Notepad++ or another software that could be better to this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace any kind of line break w not followed by a pipe with nothing:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\|)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!         # negative lookahead, zero length assertion that makes sure we do not have after:
    \|      # a pipe character
)           # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
| 1020941333    |     569|SP    |500000343 | 9|18.05.2011|15:27:00|18.05.2011|18.05.2011|Y-0444871-ENCR    |           1,93 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |Y-0444871               |
| 1020941586    |      43|SP    |500000344 |43|18.05.2011|15:41:43|18.05.2011|18.05.2011|B-0447039-ENCR    |           9,02 |BRL  |8000800000  |Juros, Comissões e T       |                  |           |                                        |    |          |     |                     |CLB082902  |     |     |                 |COEL  |COEL  |B-0447039               |
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I worked very well. Regex is something that I have tried a lot to learn and master it, but i really couldn't.

Comment: @ArnoldSouza: You're welcome, glad it helps. The following site is really intersting: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @ArnoldSouza: May I know why you have unaccepted this answer? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to find a pipe followed by a newline and use a negative lookahead `(?!` to check what is on the right of the pipe is not the pattern that starts a new line. Then replace with the first capturing group to keep the pipe..

**Find what:**

`(\|)\R(?!\|[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+\|)`

**Replace with:**

`$1`

**Explanation**

- `(\|)` Match a pipe in a capturing group
- `\R` Match unicode newline sequence
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `\|[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+\|` Match a pipe, 1+ times a space or tab, 1+ digits, 1+ space or tabs and a pipe
- `)` Close negative lookahead

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IqRQax/1)